In abstract index notation, can repeated abstract indices be replaced by repeated component indices?
Here's my attempt to prove this (I'll do so for a (2-3) tensor for notational convenience, but the same approach can be generalized to arbitrary rank tensors):
$$T^{ab}_{\ \ \ \ \ cad}=C^1_2[T^{ab}_{\ \ \ \ \ ced}]=C^1_2[T^{\mu\nu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \sigma\rho\phi}(\partial_{\mu})^a\otimes (\partial_{\nu})^b\otimes (dx^{\sigma})_c\otimes(dx^{\rho})_e\otimes(dx^{\phi})_d] \\ =T^{\mu\nu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \sigma\rho\phi}C^1_2[(\partial_{\mu})^a\otimes (\partial_{\nu})^b\otimes (dx^{\sigma})_c\otimes(dx^{\rho})_e\otimes(dx^{\phi})_d] \\ =\big(T^{\mu\nu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \sigma\rho\phi}\delta_{\mu}^{\ \ \rho}\big)(\partial_{\nu})^b\otimes (dx^{\sigma})_c\otimes(dx^{\phi})_d=T^{\mu\nu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \sigma\mu\phi}(\partial_{\nu})^b\otimes (dx^{\sigma})_c\otimes(dx^{\phi})_d \\ =T^{\mu b}_{\ \ \ \ \ c\mu d}.$$
Is this correct? And even if this is correct, does this rule really does generalize to arbitrary rank tensors or arbitrary combinations of tensors? (e.g. $T^{ab}_{\ \ \ \ cd}S^{edfg}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ha}=T^{\mu b}_{\ \ \ \ c\nu}S^{e\nu fg}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ h\mu})$

Actually, I don't know what you mean with $(\partial_i)^a$ ? Why a tangent or cotangent vector should have a lower and an upper index ? A (co)vector should only have one index.

@FredericThomas: I think the confusion is arising because I used $i,j,k,\ldots$ instead of greek letters to denote components. The abstract indices are denoted by the first few letters of the alphabet $a,b,c,\ldots$. I hope that clarifies it? Would you recommend changing $i,j,k$ to greek indices? I haven't done it so far since it's really cumbersome to type

@FredericThomas Abstract indices are, well, abstract. They are here to mean that they act on something. They are different from the Einstein indices.

I think you could have made this a lot more concise if you used a (1,1) tensor in your example :P the passive indices that aren't repeated don't contribute to the central issue I think you are asking about

@Qmechanic: How can I make the question clearer? The feedback will help me edit the question so that it can be reopened

@user9343456 I can suggest something along a different line. (Indeed I'm not sure why your question wasn't clear, personally I think your example was just a bit cumbersome). But I do suggest that you try and post this on Math.SE, if you do however, one tip is that you better mention you're tackling this issue with a physicist toolbox ;) otherwise they may shower you with tensor notation that you may find a bit incomprehensible... (speaking from experience! lol).

@Amit I will try that for sure, thanks! But I first wanted to post this on Physics SE because I'm sure many here would be comfortable with abstract index notation and its intricacies. A bit surprised to see the question get closed so quickly due to being unclear. I've made some edits and have a genuine question: does the question still seem unclear/difficult to understand?

@user9343456 Well for me as I said , I'm quite clear on what you wanted to prove here, and that you're looking basically for feedback on whether your method is correct. I only think you could have used a tensor with less indices to make it less cumbersome, it would still communicate the essence of what you want to do imho.

@user9343456 Please see if this Math.SE question and answers therein help you. It seems to me essentially the same. If it's not, I guess I didn't understand your question after all :) but I hope it's what you're looking for.

On p. 55 of Liang & Zhou, Differential Geometry and General Relativity there is the expression $T^a{}_a=T(e^{\mu*};e_\mu)=T^\mu{}_\mu$ of which your $T^{ab}{}_{cad}=T^{\mu b}{}_{c\mu d}$ is a higher order generalization that looks totally consistent since that is a tensor of type $(1,2)$ that has components
$T^{\mu\nu}{}_{\sigma\mu\phi}\,.$ Also: a smarter way than typesetting T^{\mu\nu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \sigma\mu\phi} is T^{\mu\nu}{}_{\sigma\mu\phi}.
